# What JDK should I use for netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8, netbeans-8

In Netbeans 8.2, it says to use Java JDK 8.1 or higher. When I use the latest version of JDK, Netbeans will load up but I can’t open or make new projects. When I get 8.1 I can’t use certain features of languages, like timers in Java.

What JDK should I use to have both Netbeans functioning and have all features of Java usable?

Comment: `jdk-8u191` will be useful for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [This document](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/82/install.html) describes how to install NetBeans IDE 8.2 on your system. Please see the NetBeans IDE 8.2 Release Notes for information about supported operating systems and hardware configurations for the IDE. To learn about the new features included in this release of the IDE see the [NetBeans IDE 8.2 Release Information](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/82/index.html) page.

And use [8u191 or 8u192](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) for Netbeans 8.2

Comment: This was the problem, the JDK I was using, thanks for the help

Comment: @LitsabberDudeguy If this answer has resolved your problem, you should accept it. :)

Comment: @LitsabberDudeguy I'm currently working Netbeans 8.2 with JDK 192 64 bit that is running fine in my system.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat specific to Ubuntu, or at least Linux:  install Java with `SDKman` which is somewhat like `RVM` but for Java.  Quite simple to install, it will then manage your `JDK` versions.

Additionally, `umake`, or `ubuntu-make`, will install your IDE or other developer tools.  This utility is best installed through the `snap` package manager to get the latest version.

From `umake` it's a simple command to then install developer tools such as `NetBeans`.  Currently this installs `NB` 8.2 which will **not** run on any JDK nine or higher.

Use `SDKman` to manage your `JDK` version (and `gradle`, and `kotlin`, and ...).  Use `umake` to handle your IDE version.

My two cents

*In the next week or so, `umake` should upgrade to `NetBeans` o.  There was a bit of a mixup when `Apache` took over but the `umake` maintainers are on the ball.
Or, just download `NB` 9 directly.  You'll have to use an older JDK, as specified in the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53897174/262852) answer by user5377037.*

Why are you running `NB` 8.x?